# How to user collective.documentviewer with plone for ocr in images plone 4.1.4?

Tags: python, linux, plone, tesseract

I have a plone(v.4.1.4) site standalone unified installer with collective.documentviewer 2.2.1. It is working fine as long as searching words from scanned doc, xls, open office, rtf, pdf are concerned. In case of images(containing text) uploaded as image content type, even if OCR is checked in the Document settings, the image is not supported by Document viewer. If image is uploaded as file also I am unable to search word which is part of the image after setting of appropriate image format i.e. gif,png,jpg. I have installed the necessary tesseract files which you get by the following command on my linux system:

```
dpkg -l| grep tesseract
ii  libtesseract3                        3.02.01-6                        i386         Command line OCR tool
ii  tesseract-ocr                        3.02.01-6                        i386         Command line OCR tool
ii  tesseract-ocr-eng                    3.02-2                           all          tesseract-ocr language files for English
ii  tesseract-ocr-equ                    3.02-2                           all          tesseract-ocr language files for equations
ii  tesseract-ocr-osd                    3.02-2                           all          tesseract-ocr language files for script and orientation
```

Attaching a sample gif image. [image]
I want to for example search the word "Lab" which is part of the image. The text tab does not show the words of the image embedded in this pdf. Please guide

Comment: Is there anything in the event log? You should see the status of the OCR process. Additionally, in the viewer, if you click the "text" tab you should be able to see what text was able to be detected on the pdf/image/etc. It's quite possible that tesseract just isn't good enough to pull out any text from this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/627308/vangheem thank you for a quick response. Actually the settings of the document viewer for "OCR" and "Detect text" are a little confusing. Now it does extract word when "ocr" is checked and "detect text"  is unchecked. But please note that partial words entered as search string in the documentviewer search box is not detected. Only if the word entered fully in the searchbox and is present in the ocr ed text tab, it is highlighted. While in the plone site search, partial word matches works great.Is that a drawback of documentviewer?

Comment: hhmmm, that sounds like a bug to me--perhaps the type of catalog I'm using for the OCR documents. I'm the author of documentviewer, pull requests are welcome. Otherwise, I probably won't get around to digging into it unless a client is paying...